# GetNumaHighestNodeNumber(...) returns zero on a 3990X on Windows 11?

Tags: c++, windows-10, numa, windows-11

I have some code that spins up X number of threads based on the number of logical cores in my system. I have a 3990X (128 logical cores).

On Windows 10, I can do this:

```
int numaAPI_GetNumNodes(void) 
{
    ULONG highest_node_number;
    if (!GetNumaHighestNodeNumber(&highest_node_number)) 
    {
        return 0;
    }

    return (int)highest_node_number + 1;
}
```

And then use this to allocate my threads:

```
int system_cpu_thread_count()
{
    const int num_nodes = numaAPI_GetNumNodes();
    int num_threads = 0;
    for (int node = 0; node < num_nodes; ++node) 
    {
        if (!system_cpu_is_numa_node_available(node)) 
        {
            continue;
        }

        num_threads += system_cpu_num_numa_node_processors(node);
    }

    return num_threads;
}
```

On Windows 10, this works perfectly, with `GetNumaHighestNodeNumber(...)` returning 1, but on Windows 11, it returns 0.

Now, according to [NUMA Support: Behavior starting with Windows 10 Build 20348](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/numa-support#behavior-starting-with-windows-10-build-20348), there's been a change in the API (and some suggested workarounds), but the examples provided use kernel calls, and it's unclear what I can use now to get the info I need.

Note: The docs also say that if the function returns a 0 then there's an error, and to use `GetLastError(...)` to determine the error. However `GetLastError(...)` returns a 0, which apparently means the function succeeded.

Comment: Have you followed this instruction *If the function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended error information, call GetLastError.*?

Comment: Ah, I forgot to mention that, I'll edit the post. `GetLastError(...)` returns a 0.

Comment: It is impossible. You may call GetLastError() too late, as it is not seen in the code above.

Comment: Per the [`GetNumaHighestNodeNumber()` doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/systemtopologyapi/nf-systemtopologyapi-getnumahighestnodenumber): "*The number of the highest node is not guaranteed to be the total number of nodes.*" But you are treating it as if it were.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yeah, I wonder if I should just alter my approach and use `GetLogicalProcessorInformationEx(...)` instead.

Comment: Per [NUMA Support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/numa-support): "*First of all, you will need to determine the layout of nodes in the system. To retrieve the highest numbered node in the system, use the `GetNumaHighestNodeNumber` function. Note that this number is not guaranteed to equal the total number of nodes in the system. Also, nodes with sequential numbers are not guaranteed to be close together...*"

Comment: "*... To retrieve the list of processors on the system, use the `GetProcessAffinityMask` function. You can determine the node for each processor in the list by using the `GetNumaProcessorNode[Ex]` function. Alternatively, to retrieve a list of all processors in a node, use the `GetNumaNodeProcessorMask[Ex]` function.*"

Comment: Maybe I'm not reading this correctly, but it's unclear to me how to use `GetProcessAffinityMask(...)` to retrieve the list of processors on the system: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getprocessaffinitymask